# Importing Excel Data for Isovolume Rendering Paraview

Tags: data-visualization, vtk, paraview

I am trying to visualize heat intensity data(0 to 1)based on `xyz`. I have the data in a excel file and also in a csv file. In csv, the format is as follows:

```
x, y, z, scalar
0, 1, 1, 0.489324
1, 1, 1, 0.899
.
.
.
```

Each unit on an axis represents one voxel. There are totally 12 voxels along each axis. I would like visualize something close to this -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UMnIwdQhZE4. How do i import either an excel data or csv into paraview? Is there a way to copy paste values from excel sheet into a 3d array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paraview can easily open csv files, creating a table source. Once you load your data, you can use the

1. TableToPoints: I find it the easiest option, you just have to select which column represent x,y,z. The outout is a polygonall mesh 
   or
2. TableToStructuredGrid: besides choosing the columns, you also have to write the extent - in your case I think 0-11 0-11 0-11 . I don't have much experience with this, but I think you also have to be careful if your data is x-fastest or not. The output in this case is a structuredGrid
3. If you have to do something more complicated, you can use the programmable filter and change the output format. For examples see the paraview guide. For suitable formats, here is a nice answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7667417/1136458

Comment: see also http://www.paraview.org/Wiki/ParaView/Data_formats#Read_a_CSV_file_into_Paraview

Comment: I tried using TableToStructuredGrid on csv data and the result looks like this. http://imgur.com/XuxA0yv. The voxels are zig zags. I don't know why.

Comment: maybe the order of the columns is wrong... I think it's X: 012012012 Y:001122 Z:000111222 but I don't have a working example here

Comment: I think it worked now. I changed the order and it renders much better.