# Paraview importing vector data from excel (csv file)

Tags: excel, csv, vector, paraview

I know how to import scalars into paraview thanks to this answer: 
[Importing Excel Data for Isovolume Rendering Paraview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567753/importing-excel-data-for-isovolume-rendering-paraview)

I have csv file like this:

x coord;y coord;z coord;scalar

0;0;0;0

1;0;0;1

0;1;0;2

1;1;0;3

0;0;1;4

1;0;1;5

0;1;1;6

1;1;1;7

How should csv file look like and wich filter (with scalars I used "table to structured grid") should I use to have vectors inside cube? Is it possible to use excel to import vector fileds into paraview? I´ve searched a lot but I found mostly informations about vtk files.

Cube should have vectors inside like in this video: (time 8:20)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1RATo2swM8

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to save a separate column for each vector component. The `Table to Structured Grid` filter should read each column as a separate scalar. Then, you can use the Calculator filter to convert the several vector components into one vector. Let's say you name you vector components VX, VY, and VZ. Your Calculator expression would be `VX*iHat + VY*jHat + VK*kHat`.

Comment: CSV file looked like this:                                                                                   x coord;y coord;z coord;vector x;vector y;vector z
0;0;0;1;4;1
1;0;0;1;1;2
0;1;0;2;1;2
1;1;0;3;1;2
0;0;1;1;1;1
1;0;1;0;1;0
0;1;1;0;2;2
1;1;1;0;1;1     And it worked. Thank you.